# How to call the API to get the json data in angular the url is tcp server with port number

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8, rest

I have an angular application and I have to call the API from the tcp server with port number 9999 and the API is **http:127.0.0.1:9999** how to get the json response in console from the url .

My service.ts file is

**.service.ts**

```
export class DashboardService {
dta:any;
 url:'http:127.0.0.1:9999'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {

      this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(dta=>{
      console.log(dta);
    })
  }
```

But I am not able to get the response can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: Can you share with us the response of your endpoin, using curl, for example? Maybe the problem was the way you are returning the data.

Comment: That URL (http:127.0.0.1:9999) is not valid

Comment: Should be http://